# Kotlin/Java - How to identify internal packages?

Tags: java, kotlin, logging, jvm, package

#### TL;DR:

Internal package: Packages that Java programs can use without importing external jars or explicitly specifying extra classpaths, like `java.lang.Exception`.

I need an implementation of this function:

```kotlin
/**
 * @param package Package name (Eg. "java.lang.Exception")
 * @return True if this package is an internal package.
 */
fun isInternal(package: String): Boolean
{
    // What is the most efficient implementation here?
}
```

---

#### Example Cases:

```kotlin
isInternal("java.lang.Exception") // true
isInternal("org.hydev.Test") // false
isInternal("com.sun.net.httpserver") // true
isInternal("sun.misc.BASE64Encoder") // true
isInternal("javax.xml.ws") // true
// But there must be more internal packages that don't start with java. or com.sun. or sun.
```

---

#### Long story:

I'm building HyLogger, a logger library focused on color-coding, and here is the problem I ran to:

[image: FQCN problem]

When `Throwable.printStackTrace()` is called, the first entry in the stack trace that's not from my logger library would be `java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream.println:749`. Therefore, when searching through the stack trace to find the most useful entry for FQCN, internal packages need to be filtered. An easy solution is to filter out entries that start with `java.`, `sun.`, or `com.sun.`, but there must be more internal packages prefixes than those three, which is why I asked this question.

Comment: "*An easy solution is to filter out entries that start with java., sun., or com.sun., but there must be more internal packages prefixes than those three*" not really. you pretty much covered it

Comment: Don't forget `jdk.`. Also, if you are on java 8, you can check it the classloader is `null`.

Comment: Would this include framework classes built into the runtime, like the Android framework on an Android device?

Comment: @RyanM Ideally, it would include essential framework classes. However, it is probably impossible to implement if framework classes are included, so I'm limiting the scope to only classes built into JVM.

Comment: Your question is essentially unanswerable since it is based on a misconception. Classes and packages are not *"built into JVM"*. You need to define yourself what to consider "internal packages". Depending on a version of Java Runtime, there are different packages supplied with the Runtime. Do you really want colors to vary depending on a version of JDK used to run the application? For example, should `javax.xml.ws` be considered as an internal or an external package?

Comment: @apangin Thanks for pointing that out. I've clarified that internal packages are "packages that Java programs can use without importing or explicitly specifying extra classpath." Therefore `javax.xml.ws` is an internal package.

Comment: In java 8 and before you could probably figure out if a class came from rt.jar or some_vendor_specific_extension_jar.jar and define those classes as internal.

Comment: `javax.xml.ws` is available in JDK 8; requires extra JVM option `--add-modules` in JDK 9-10; and is not available entirely without third party dependencies since JDK 11. So, with your current definition of "internal package", a user may see different output depending on the JDK version. IMO, this may look confusing. Why not just specifying a stable list of packages, regardless of whether they are provided by the bootstrap class loader or not?

Comment: @apangin Ok, I didn't know it varies depending on the JDK version. I guess specifying a static list of packages accomplishes this purpose better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your definition of an "internal class" corresponds to a class that is loaded by the JVM's bootstrap classloader.

From Java 9 onwards, the `StackTraceElement` class has a method called `getClassLoaderName()` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getClassLoaderName--)).  This returns a `String`, or `null` if the classloader has no name.  The bootstrap classloader should have no name ... or (possibly) a name that you can distinguish.

Alternatively, you could call `Class.forName` on the class, and then call `getClassLoader()` on the `Class` object.  If the class was loaded by the bootclassloader, that call will return `null`.

---

Even if your definition of an "internal class" doesn't exactly mean "loaded by the bootstrap classloader", it probably does relate to the classes classloader.  The above approach should still work ... with some tweaks.